# Problems when the user access some routes in my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which my main route is defined like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Acesso", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

There are two main controllers in my app: `Access` and `Main`. When the user enters the application, it goes to `Access` like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    RepositorioAcesso repositorio = new RepositorioAcesso();
    string login = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split(new[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].ToLower();
    Acesso acesso = repositorio.RecuperarAcesso(login, false);

    if (acesso == null)
    {
        ViewBag.mensagem = "User Not Found.";
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Logando", "Acesso", new { @login = login });
    }
}
```

And here's the `Logando` method:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult Logando(string login)
{
    RepositorioAcesso repositorio = new RepositorioAcesso();
    RepositorioAgendamentosCliente repositorioAgendamentos = new RepositorioAgendamentosCliente();
    Acesso acesso = repositorio.RecuperarAcesso(login, true);

    Session.Timeout = 900;
    Session["Login"] = acesso.Login;
    Session["LoginCompleto"] = login.ToUpper();
    Session["Nome"] = acesso.Nome;
    Session["TipoMenu"] = ObterLayout(acesso);
    Session["PaginaPrincipal"] = ObterPaginaPrincipal(acesso);
    Session["Loja"] = acesso.Loja.LojaBase;
    Session["ADABAS"] = acesso.Loja.LojaBase;
    Session["Acesso"] = acesso;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Principal");
}
```

I did it this way because the users wanted to login using their windows account information. But if the user is recently employed by the company, he/she couldn't appear in our records because the information was not updated. So, i check if they are in our database first. If they are, then i get their info.

Sometimes, the users would access the app directly going for the Main/Index route, which would throw an error because there would be no session information about them. So I did this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Session["lista"] = new List<Alta>();
    Session["cliente"] = new Cliente();
    Session["Configuracao"] = new ConfiguracaoLoja();
    Acesso acesso = GetAcessoSession();

    if (acesso == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Acesso");
    }

    // rest of the code here    
}
```

It works, but not all the time, as I get some errors, which ask me to turn custom errors on on my web.config. (I still have to check those errors, as i changed my web-config 10 minutes ago).

Is there an more efficient way to check if there is session information about the user and redirect them if needed? I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 btw.

Comment: You will want to avoid saving too much information in Session - that's typically persisted with a session-state cookie that has to be carried across every HTTP request. Instead, I would recommend using something like the claims-based Identity framework, only storing the minimal you need to identify a user on each request. If you could explain what each session variable is supposed to represent, I can try adding an actual answer to get you started.

Comment: You can actually ignore those three session variables. The one that matters is inside  Session["Acesso"], which is the current user.